# The 3-level Azure Traffic Manager doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I created a 3-level Azure Traffic Manager. But it doesn't work.

At the top tier, it's called `myroot.trafficmanager.net`.
At the middle tier, there are 2 nested traffic manager profile called `mysub1.trafficmanager.net` and `mysub2.trafficmanager.net`.
At the bottom tier, each nested traffic manager profile has 2 endpoints, Azure websites.

The balancing method of the top tier is Round Robin.
The balancing method of the middle tier is Performance.

I used Azure PowerShell cmdlets to create the mapping between the top tier and the middle tier.

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureTrafficManagerProfile -Name “myroot"
PS C:\> $TrafficManagerProfile = Get-AzureTrafficManagerProfile -Name "myroot"
PS C:\> Add-AzureTrafficManagerEndpoint -TrafficManagerProfile $TrafficManagerProfile -DomainName "mysub1.trafficmanager.net" -Status "Enabled" -Type "TrafficManager" | Set-AzureTrafficManagerProfile
PS C:\> $TrafficManagerProfile = Get-AzureTrafficManagerProfile -Name "myroot"
PS C:\> Add-AzureTrafficManagerEndpoint -TrafficManagerProfile $TrafficManagerProfile -DomainName "mysub2.trafficmanager.net" -Status "Enabled" -Type "TrafficManager" | Set-AzureTrafficManagerProfile
```

After the above command is done. I can use `nslookup myroot.trafficmanager.net` command to see the IP have been directed to the right endpoint. But when I open `myroot.trafficmanager.net` in the browser, I got the error:

> Error 404 - Web app not found.

I would appreciate if anyone could give me any clue.

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably due to the fact that your top-level Traffic Manager domain (`myroot.trafficmanager.net`) is not mapped as custom domain to your web app (Web Site). And this is because, your Web Site only knows about `mysub1.trafficmanager.net`).

You can solve your issue by using custom domain and correctly [map your custom domain to your Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/). Then, also [map your custom domain to your Traffic Manager Domain](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/sspencer/post/2015/01/15/Setting-Custom-Domain-for-Traffic-Manager-and-Azure-Websites.aspx).